# Should I use prepareForValidation of FormRequest to passing params for validation request?

Tags: laravel

I want to pass user_id and post_id to formRequest. So I use prepareForValidation to merge to the request like that done in the code below. Is that way ok or I should be passing params on Controller?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'content' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:\App\Models\User,id',
        'post_id' => 'required|exists:\App\Models\Post,id'
    ];
}

public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'post_id' => $this->post->id
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please write the code in the code block and not present it in an image.

Comment: I was edited, tks.

Comment: why would you need to validate anything about the current authenticated user?

Comment: For simple integers  i just would go for standanrd validation rules, like `['required', 'integer', 'min:1', 'exists:table,id']`; i would use `prepareForValidation()` to sanitize text inputs since user could have placed some malicious code in the strings.

Comment: @lagbox I want to merge both user_id and post_id to the request so in controller i just call `$request->validated()` as a attribute to create a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's ok but remove unneeded checks like:

> exists:\App\Models\User,id,

and

> exists:\App\Models\Post,id

I think all you need to make it

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'content' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'post_id' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

To avoid hitting the database for no reason the **user** is the **current user** so no need to check and the **post** in **the current request** so it can not be deleted.

*Note:*

(The business may be different for the post based on your project. I mean may admin can delete it so the normal user can not do the action then keep this rule for post_id (exists:\App\Models\Post,id) )

Answer (score 1):

If Route look like

```
Route::patch('posts/{post}', 'update');
```

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'content' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'post_id' => $this->route('post')->id
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

M too late but here is a smart way.
Before validation code in controller just use below 2 methods.

1: `$request->request->remove('field_name');`

2: `$request->request->add(['field_name' => 'modified_value']);`

Good to go.